# Javascript callback return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Using node.js, I am connecting to my redis database and returning the values into an array.  However, in order to return the values, I must use a callback function to get them out of the scope.  I have seen many examples on SO of callback functions in action, and mine works just like all the others I have seen, however, when I call the function as an option in `res.render`, it tries to return the parent function rather than the callback.  How do I return the callback function's value to the `players:` option?

**Parent Function**

```
function openPlayers(callback) {
  var players = [];
  db.hgetall("players", function(err, objs) {
    // Objects of Response
    for (var k in objs) {
      // Items are the individual key-value object
      var newPlayer = {};
      var items = JSON.parse(objs[k]);
      for (var x in items) {
        // x is the key for each object
        newPlayer[x] = items[x];
      }
      players.push(newPlayer);
    }
    callback(players);
  });
}
```

**Location of Callback Function**

```
exports.newPlayer = function(req, res) {
  res.render('newPlayer', {
    title: 'New Player',
    players: (openPlayers(function(ps) { //callback function
              return(ps);
            }))
  });
};
```

Comment: Returning from asynchronous callback is useless. You have to invert the logic, and call res.render from your callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't since `openPlayers` is async and doesn't return any value, that's why it takes a callback. What you could do is something like this however:

```
exports.newPlayer = function(req, res) {

    openPlayers(function (ps) {
        res.render('newPlayer', {
            title: 'New Player',
            players: ps
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Ok, ok... this async stuff is ridiculous.  Thanks so much for the great answer!